# Iccube Rest API, how to execute a ExecuteMdxScript from C#?

Tags: c#, rest, iccube

I know how to trigger a load schema using "FULL_LOAD_SCHEMA [{CubeName}]"

```
String postData;
postData = $@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" soap:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><soap:Body><Execute xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis""><Command><Statement xsi:type=""xsd:string"">FULL_LOAD_SCHEMA [{CubeName}]</Statement></Command></Execute></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
```

I know as well how to achieve what I want using the IcCube Rest API test IDE like :
[image]

My problem (below) is that I need to map endpoint but also json parameters from a C# webApplication.

I tried :

```
var url = "https://www.mySite.fr/icCube/xmla";

var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";

httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic aW1wb3J0X3NlcnZpY2VAcGtjcy5mcjpQQHNzdzByZDMkLVlzJDYlaFc=";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

var data = @"{
  ""schemaName"": ""Sales"",
  ""script"": ""create category hierarchy [Stats].[MaStatHierarchyAPI]""
}";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
   streamWriter.Write(data);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

but this gives me following error :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>XMLAnalysisError.0x5496d617</faultcode><faultstring>unexpected processing error : Pretty print error!</faultstring><detail><Error ErrorCode="1419171351" Description="unexpected processing error : Pretty print error!"/></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I think the problem is I don't know where/how to mention the endpoint is "ExecuteMdxScript".

If I change the top url to :

```
var url = "https://www.mySite.fr/icCube/xmla/ExecuteMdxScript";
```

I get following error :

```
<h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
<h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint of the [Rest API](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/api/overview.php) is (for a server running localhost:8282):

```
http://localhost:8282/icCube/api
```

So in your case for [ExecuteMdxScript](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/api/ExecuteMdxScript.php):

```
http://localhost:8282/icCube/api/console/mdx/ExecuteMdxScript
```

You're getting an error as you're hitting the XMLA interface instead.